# Using Excel VBA to Create Graphs

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very daunting task ahead of me and I'm wondering if it's possible to automate it with VBA.  I apologize for breaking the cardinal rule of "show us what you've tried first", but I have very limited experience with VBA.

See the attached screenshot.  I have an Excel file with about 107 unique points in column D.  For each unique point ID, I need to create a graph of columns G, J, L, and W.  Currently, I've been doing this manually.  There is 12 months of data (July 1, 2017 - July 31, 2018).  Ideally, there would be one reading per month; however, some months there are points that have multiple readings.[image]

My question before I go down the rabbit hole is: is this possible with Excel VBA?

Edit: see screenshot of an example graph I'm trying to create.[image]

Comment: So there are 107 distinct IDs in total. Measurements for these can occur more than once per month on some occasions though generally once per month? Your "measures" are very different . Were you planning on potting them all one one chart per ID over time? There are methods of adjusting disparate measures to plot on one chart... a normalising so to speak. There answer is probably yes there will be a way in VBA but you need to decide how you are going to meaningfully chart this and handle multiple observations with a given month e.g. will you average?

Comment: Yes, all unique IDs would have their own chart.  I'll go back and upload a picture of one of the charts I've done as an example.

Comment: You may be able to generate a pivotchart to do this for you. Do you really need VBA?

Comment: Well, if I was going to create individual graphs for each individual point, I was under the impression that I would need to either do it manually or use VBA.  Pivotcharts can do this??

Comment: How dair u @QHarr (also, great idea with pivot!). OP, **1**Turn this into a pivot table. **2**Create a pivot chart and then **3** add a `Slicer` for `Point Name`. This will let you select which `Point Name` you want to view and the chart will update accordingly. There are plenty of *How-To's* online for all of these steps.  Doing this will also save your book a lot of space memory wise and will look cleaner. Looking at 120 different charts cannot be ideal for anyone looking for valuable insights.

Comment: I’m definitely gonna have to try that method and I’ll report back here.

Comment: No luck.  It gets me close but I need separate graphs each on their own worksheets.